# Getting jar file from Git Source folder

Tags: java

I tried to get the Jar of the following project https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/tree/master/jasypt-spring2 
Using the Jar command line :

```
$ java cf jasypt-spring2.jar jasypt-spring2
```

I get the following error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class cf
```

I understand the problem so i tried to download the jar using maven:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasypt-spring2</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And i get the information from the project pom.xml:

```
 <groupId>
 <artifactId>
 <version>
```

But i get a compilation problem using Eclipse IDE:

```
  Missing artifact org.jasypt:jasypt-spring2:jar:1.9.3-SNAPSHOT
```

What is the right way to generate the jar file?

Comment: Maven central is a release repository. It doesn't contain snapshots. Use `<version>1.9.3</version>`

Comment: Why not download it from the central Maven repo as given [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3)?

Comment: Use the `jar` command, not the `java` command.